# RSpec, FactoryBot and model callbacks with ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

This has most likely been asked many times but I can't seem to find anything as I'm not sure what I should actually be searching for.

I have a model called `car`, which has a `after_commit :new_car, on: :create` and in the `new_car` method I have an ActiveJob class which goes off and calls a number of API's to fetch extra information about the car. How would I go about testing this with RSpec and FactoryBot? When I call `FactoryBot.create(:car)` I want the extra information so I can confirm the columns in the database have values as I set the records status to `complete` when the job has finished, which in turn, will display the record to the end users. As you might have already guessed `FactoryBot.create(:car)` is currently not working due to the `after_commit` callback. Code is below. Please let me know if something doesn't make sense or you need to see more code. Thank you.

**car.rb**

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: [:complete, :in_progress, :failed]

  after_commit :new_car, on: :create

  def new_car
    NewCarJob.perform_later(self.id)
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/cars.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :car do
    reg_number "FG780WE"

    # extra info from ActiveJob
    color ""
    Doors ""
    stolen ""
    finance ""
    mot_expires_at ""
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: you'd have to make code env dependent but its not that great...
The main issue in the end is not surprisingly that you rely on callbacks instead of executing code in context.

Comment: Are you implying that callbacks are bad? if you are, can you elaborate why you think this.

Comment: I totally think they are bad. The point is they run all the time outside of any context. And this is striking you in your tests. If you create a CreateCar class to be called by the controller, you can move the callback there and it wont annoy you for your specs.